# Calculating the Y value in xy diagram and how to plot color gamuts in 3D

Tags: colors, plotly, diagram, color-space, cielab

I am trying to plot 3D gamut for srgb or even xyY diagram. But i dont know how to generate the mesh for it. I am trying to achieve something like this in plotly: [srgb gamut in 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuPai.gif)

I dont know how to calculate the Y values in the inner points of the spectrum locus. I also want to somehow create a mesh of CIE xyY hull, but i dont know how exactly.

Hello everyone, currently i have problem visualising color gamut in 3D space. Here is how I am progressing.

I have x_bar,y_bar,z_bar data from the cie 1931 XYZ 2-degree observer.

I know i can plot this data in 3D, by using the corresponding x_bar = x, y_bar = y, z_bar = z → That creates the color line shown in the graph

I can plot this data, so it is x+y+z=1, and project it onto a plane - The plane is symbolized by red triangle, and the dots on it are the projected points.

X = x/x+y+z

Y = y/x+y+z

Z = z/x+y+z

Coloring is made by this function (i am plotting the points into plotly graph):

```
// Function to convert XYZ color to RGB color
      function xyzToRgb(x, y, z) {
        const r = x * 3.2406 + y * -1.5372 + z * -0.4986;
        const g = x * -0.9689 + y * 1.8758 + z * 0.0415;
        const b = x * 0.0557 + y * -0.204 + z * 1.057;

        // Convert the RGB values to the range 0-1
        const normalize = (v) =>
          v <= 0.0031308 ? v * 12.92 : 1.055 * Math.pow(v, 1 / 2.4) - 0.055;
        return [normalize(r), normalize(g), normalize(b)].map((v) =>
          Math.round(v * 255)
        );
      }
```

[My projected points in the 3D space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFVu1.png)

To plot it into 2D, i can make small change, that Z = 0, so i look at it from the top down, and i get the spectrum locus

[My spectrum locus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYLGJ.png)

Now, my goal is to plot different gamuts in the 3D space, i am using plotly, but essentially i am trying to somehow generate data, i can use to plot it into my 3D graph

I know color cannot be correctly represented, because of the whole concept of CIE diagram, but i have seen pictures like this:

[xyY diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4azQ.jpg)

[srgb color gamut in 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mixPJ.gif)
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SRGB_gamut_within_CIExyY_color_space_mesh.webm)

I dont know how to calculate the “inner” values in the spectrum locus and their Y value ( i only have x,y values), or even their correct color for that matter. I have spectrum locus, and i also know for example the position of primaries, but i dont know how to correctly calculate the Y values in 3D space to get mesh like in the video or in the picture. Maybe i am missing something obvious, so i am here asking for any advice.

PS: There is a mathlab function : plotChromaticity("ColorSpace","uv","View",3,"BrightnessThreshold",0),
but it is in some background api that is not public, but for example that also plots the color in some way [Mathlab function output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elHWt.png)

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Afaik, this is not possible in Plotly because the Mesh3D API does not have a way to define colour per-vertex: https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/ It has been like that for years and is problematic. That being said, Colour has all the API you need to create the correct geometry, etc…: https://www.colour-science.org/ We have made recently a new repo that covers exactly what you are trying to do: https://github.com/colour-science/colour-visuals